# Como pasar variable de JQuery a Servlet de Java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html5, servlets

Me gustaria saber como enviar una variable capturada por ***JQuery*** o ***Javascript*** hasta un ***Servlet***. Trabajo con ***JSP***.

Comparto el siguiente código que utilizo. Se trata simplemente de tomar los valores de una fila seleccionada en una tabla y enviar los resultados a un ***Servlet***.

***Código***

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="css/test.css" TYPE="text/css" MEDIA=screen>

<script
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table id="table">
        <tr>
            <td>1 Ferrari F138</td>
            <td>1 000€</td>
            <td>1 200€</td>
            <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>F138</td>
            <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2 Ferrari F138</td>
            <td>1 000€</td>
            <td>1 200€</td>
            <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>F138</td>
            <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3 Ferrari F138</td>
            <td>1 000€</td>
            <td>1 200€</td>
            <td>Model monopostu stajne Scuderia Ferrari pre sezónu 2013</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>F138</td>
            <td>Klik pre detaily</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" name="OK" class="ok" value="OK" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#table tr").click(function() {
            $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
            var value = $(this).find('td:first').html();
            alert(value);
            location.href = "controller?var=" + value;
        });

        $('.ok').on('click', function(e) {
            alert($("#table tr.selected td:first").html());
        });
        
        
        
    </script>
    

</body>
</html>
```

***El servlet***

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet("/controller")
public class controller extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public controller() {
        super();

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());

    
        String value = request.getParameter("value");

        System.out.println(value);
                
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

}
```

Todos los ejemplos que he visto hasta ahora, son las de enviar parámetros desde el ***Servlet*** y tomarlos con ***Javascript***, pero no en sentido contrario. Lo mas cercano que encontré fue el `location.href = "controller?var=" + value;`, el cual me envía al ***Servlet*** pero el dato que recibo es nulo.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar trabajar con formularios en HTML

```
<form action="/tu_ruta" id="target" method="post">
  <label for="POST-name">Nombre:</label>
  <input id="POST-name" type="text" name="name">
  <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

y enviar la informacion con jquery

```
$( "#target" ).submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes tener en cuenta que tu función que obtiene la fila de la tabla se esta ejecutando en el lado del cliente y que tu servlet esta en el back lo que tienes que hacer es hacer una petición http desde tu función jquery hacia tu servlet para ello utiliza ajax

```
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: URL,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    success:function(response) {
     ...
}
});
```

El tipo de petición que hagas depende de la funcionalidad que vaya a tener dicho servlet si solo va a consumir información ocupa GET si es para hacer un update POST eliminar DELETE y así.

en caso de que sea GET ya que veo que es el método que estas implementando el contenido se envía en la cabecera de la petición

de manera que crea un objeto y haz un encode para evitar conflictos con posibles caracteres especiales

```
var trObject = {
 td1:"...",
 td2:"...",
 td3:"...",
 td4:"...",
 td5:"...",
 ...
 };
 var URL = "/controller?tr="+encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(trObject));
 //despues de esto va la peticion con ajax por especial atencion en la var URL
```

de esta manera tu objeto estará encodeado en la cabecera de la petición.

del lado del servlet solo obtén el parámetro y haz un decode

```
String decodeTr = URLDecoder.decode(request.getParameter("tr"), "UTF-8");
```

y de esta manera obtendras el json como texto plano ya si lo quieres serializar ocupa la libreria gson o jackson etc...

Answer (score 0):

Solucioné el problema con `location.href = "../controlador?var=" + value;`. En el ***Servlet*** recojí el valor con `String value = request.getParameter("var");`.

Gracias